# Splitting a string caused ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am trying to split a Spanish string in Java. And i got the following exception:

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

The string i am trying to split is: **pin pon es un muñeco**

Debuger shows the following error:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Splitting statement:

```
String[] splitVideoTitle = tvTitle.getText().toString().split("\\s+");
```

The line of code that caused the above index exception is in this line of code:

```
String firstWords = splitVideoTitle[0] + " " + splitVideoTitle[1];
```

Any suggestions to avoid this exception is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the split statement you used?

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1` You string **hasn't been split** at all.

Comment: I have updated my post with the splitting statement

Comment: while testing your split statement it should work. Is this the only title that you are trying to split, or are you looping over an array? Also what does `getText()` return?

Comment: Actually i am getting many strings through a web-service API. The getText returns the statement:  pin pon es un muñeco

Comment: Then it could be possible that one of these titles does not contain a whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add a test :

```
   String firstWords = "";
if(splitVideoTitle.length>1){
        firstWords = splitVideoTitle[0] + " " + splitVideoTitle[1];
    }
    else firstWords=splitVideoTitle[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

That error simply means that the array `splitVideoTitle` has only one element at index `splitVideoTitle[0]`. I assume that this is due to the fact the the full video title does not contain the split character, or the split character is at the begin or end of the title.

Try this:

```
String firstWords;
if (splitVideoTitle.length >= 2) {
    firstWords = splitVideoTitle[0] + " " + splitVideoTitle[1];
} else if (splitVideoTitle.length == 1) {
    firstWords = splitVideoTitle[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code by assigning the value received by Textview to another variable and your code works

```
    String a = "pin pon es un muñeco";
    String[] splitVideoTitle = a.split("\\s+");
    String firstWords = splitVideoTitle[0] + " " + splitVideoTitle[1];
    Log.i("TAG", "first word" + firstWords);
```

may be "tvTitle.getText().toString()" this is creating the issue, or returning null..please check the values returned by Textview using LOG.